# Global parameters in routing, using annotations

Tags: symfony, routes, config

I would like to restrict some of the routing parameters, but as it is a complex and repeating rule, I would like to have it set in the projects config file.

The solution is well described in Symfony's documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/service_container_parameters.html), but what is omitted is how to use it with annotation routing. It's neither shown nor said it can't be done.

Question is, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way `@Route("/%app.parameter%")`

Comment: This works, thank you. I wander why it's not included in the docs.

Comment: Yes, sometimes there is more documentation in files than in docs.